# Save and load the font generated using FreeTypeFontGenerator

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my Android App, I am using FreeTypeFontGenerator for generating a font of different size using the TTF file. This takes nearly 3 sec to start my App. I cam e to know that the font can be generated when the app is opened very first time and saved for future openings / use.

**Questions**

1. How to save the font ?
2. How to access / load the saved font in future openings / use
3. Does this need the permission of external storage from Marshmallow version ?

Below is the sample of my code relate to FreeTypeFontGenerator

```
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("data/boldarial.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();

    parameter.size = 47;
    fontRatingRec = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    fontRatingRec.setColor(70f / 255, 104f / 255, 163f / 255, 1f);
    fontRatingRec.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    parameter.size = 54;
    fontRatingButtonRec = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    fontRatingButtonRec.setColor(45f / 255, 64f / 255, 98f / 255, 1f);
    fontRatingButtonRec.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    generator.dispose();
```

Comment: This is an old question, go [gdx-smart-font](https://github.com/jrenner/gdx-smart-font).

Comment: private FileHandle getFontFile(String filename, int fontSize) { 
    return Gdx.files.local(generatedFontDir + fontSize + "_" + filename); 
  } 
Does this needs a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in android ?